# Adding a mesh adds duplicates of it onto my donut!

Tags: mesh, objects, camera

I'm trying to follow Blender Guru's video - Part 12. I was trying to add in a new plane mesh. I was able to get a plane. However, I also generated multiple planes on top of each other, and they all cut through my donut icing! I don't know how to get rid of this. I've been searching for hours and it's been really frustrating me!! Thank you for anyone who is able to help me!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from your outliner, the new plane is being added to the *Oreo Globes* collection (which I assume is being instanced on the icing, which is why multiple planes are appearing). To fix it, either select your "main scene" collection (the one that contains the light, camera, etc...) before adding the plane, or just drag the plane in the outliner out of the instanced collection (to your main scene collection).

[image: Collection]

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. the first solution worked!